# difference between FD steps and scaling for the design variables

Tags: openmdao

if i have a design variable that has lower and upper bounds of 0 and 1e6 and an initial value of 1e5
it surely is very insensitive to the default finite difference steps of 1e-6

is the correct way of overcoming this problem ; 
a) change FD step size f.e. to 5e4 
b) scale the design variable with 'scaler' of 1e6 and set the lower upper bounds to 0 and 1, while keeping the default FD steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "a" is your best bet if you are using the latest (OpenMDAO 2.x).

When you call `declare_partials` for a specific derivative in a component, or when you call `approx_totals` on a group, you can pass in an optional argument called "step", which contains the desired stepsize. Since your variable spans [0, 1e6], I think maybe a step size between 1e1 and 1e3 would work for you.

Idea "b" wouldn't actually work at present for fixing the FD problem. The step size you declare is applied to the unscaled value of the input, so you would still have the same precision problem.  This is true for both kinds of scaling (1. specified on add_output, and 2. specified on add_design_var). Note though that you may still want to scale this problem anyway because the optimizer may work better on a scaled problem. If you do this then, you should still declare the larger "step" size mentioned above.

BTW, another option is to use a relative stepsize in the 'fd' calculation by setting the "step_calc" argument to "rel". This turns the absolute stepsize into a relative stepsize. However, I don't recommend this here because your range includes zero, and when it is close to zero, the stepsize falls back to an absolute one to prevent it from being too tiny.

Comment: thanks for your answer, some follow ups
`

--1)  if i set the step_calc='rel' and step=0.1 this would be the step size is 10 percent of the initial value ? 
--2)   when the optimizer starts it steps one forward one backward (for central) and then jumps to another area (does it use the same step size to look for the gradients within the secondary search?)
--3)  you mention with the normalization the optimizer work better. I keep hearing this. For example normalizing objective function with its initial value etc. I do not see how this is effective is there mathematical background for this.

Comment: 1) Correct, except it's 10% of the current value. That's why it's bad if it gets close to zero. 2) You mean if the step is relative? For absolute stepsizes, the step is always the same. For relative stepsize, it recomputes it based on current value. We don't do any kind of stepsize adaptation otherwise.

Comment: 3) A couple of things off the top of my head: you definitely want to normalize at least the constraints so that ones with tiny values don't get de-emphasized compared to the others. Same thing for desvars, where for large valued vars, the gradient would appear insensitive compared to other vars.  Also, any overall tuning parameters that are absolute instead of relative (e.g., absolute convergence tolerance, absolute feasibility measure) also need to be adjusted for overall problem magnitude if the problem isn't scaled nicely.

Comment: ok so basically if i have 2 constraints independent form each other but output of the same component, say con 1>100 years life time and con2==20 m diameter. 
then the code could be 
add_constraint(con1,lower=1,scaler=1/100)
add_constraint(con2,equals=1,scaler=1/20)
because scaler description is : the value to multiply the model value to get the scaled value.

Comment: Ooops, see comment below.

Comment: Though wait, i just noticed the lower and equals. You should specify those in unscaled format, so `add_constraint(con1, lower=100. scaler=1/100)`, and `add_constraint(con2, equals=20, scaler=1/20)`.

Comment: that is confusing
say if i have a component that outputs the lifetime and an objective (both changes with respect to a single input)
the lifetime values will be in the order of 100 and i want it to be at least 100 while minimizing the objective. if i set the lower =100 and scaler = 1/100. the components output will be multiplied with the scaler right ? so ~100 will become ~1. then why do i still set the lower constraint 100.

Comment: Actually, when you specify these scaling factors in add_constraint, only the driver ever sees the scaled value. The rest of openmdao computation sees unscaled. There is a separate scaling of outputs that is also allowed (in add_output), and with these, the scaled values are seen in openmdao, but these are typically used to help solver convergence and not for the driver.

Comment: ok, i guess one could say the scaling within this step is for ''driver convergence'' only. 

thanks for your answers